# MariaDB procedure multiple parameter for use IN() statement

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb

i try collecting some data over different tables.

My procedure works fine for 1 ID in pfid but now i want supply more IDs to use it in the IN().

DB is: 10.9.4-MariaDB-1:10.9.4

its seems only 1. parameter is used then the results should be the same

```
CALL `tradeResults`('2022-01-01', NOW(), '128,131')
 [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 2023-03-03
            [tr] => 9122.0954
            [div] => 4350.6995
            [qr] => -14803.13235
        )

CALL `tradeResults`('2022-01-01', NOW(), '131,128')
 [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 2023-03-03
            [tr] => 1496.8574
            [div] => 453.0200
            [qr] => -82.65128
        )
```

the proc

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `tradeResults`(IN `sDate` DATE, IN `eDate` DATE, IN `pfids` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        dateStart DATE DEFAULT sDate;
    DECLARE
        dateEnd DATE DEFAULT eDate;
    DECLARE quotetoday decimal(50, 12);
    DECLARE divtoday decimal(50, 12);
    SET divtoday = 0;
    WHILE (dateStart <= dateEnd)
        DO
            IF (WEEKDAY(dateStart) < 5) THEN
                SELECT dateStart as `date`, COALESCE(0 + SUM(`trade_result`), 0) as `tr`

                     , (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(`total_dividend_received`),0)  FROM `dividends` WHERE `portfolio_id` IN
                                                                                                  (pfids) AND  `created` <= NOW()) as `div`
                     , COALESCE((SELECT  SUM(`priceNowSumAll`)-SUM(`buyInSumAll`) FROM
                    `single_instrument_date_performance` WHERE `portfolio_id`IN (pfids) AND  `date` =
                                                                                            dateStart group by `date`), 0) as `qr`


                FROM `sells` WHERE portfolio_id IN (pfids) AND DATE (`created`) <= dateStart;
            END IF;
            SET
                dateStart = dateStart + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
        END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

edit:
**Solved**

Solution was:

Change input-typ to Json and change the where to "WHERE  JSON_CONTAINS ( pfids, portfolio_id) AND DATE (`created`) <= dateStart"

The Call is now:
CALL `tradeResults`('2022-01-01', NOW(), '[131,128]')

Comment: A couple of options: [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/) and [JSON_CONTAINS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_contains/) (setting the input parameter to a JSON array).

Comment: @wchiquito thanks the json was the way i was looking for.  changed the  portfolio_id IN (pfids) JSON_CONTAINS ( pfids, portfolio_id)  and supply the pfids as array